# preg_replace to make Tweeter ID

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to replace `http://` or `https://` from my string with @.

```
eg: $twitter_id = 'http://abcuser';
```

result I want is '@abcuser'

What I am trying is

```
$twitter_id = 'http://abcuser';
$match = '/http:/';
$replace = '@';
$new_id = preg_replace($match, $replace, $twitter_id);
echo 'Tweet ID:'.$new_id;
```

But not getting any proper result.
Please Help.

Comment: `$match = '/http:\/\//';`?

Comment: If you want to replace `http://`, why are you only replacing `http:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[No need for regex](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113243) here, use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$new_id = str_replace(array('http', 'https'), '@', $twitter_id);
echo 'Tweet ID' . $new_id; // @abcuser
```

---

If you **do** decide to use regex here, you can implement it like this:

```
$pattern = '/(?:http|https):\/\//';
$replace = '@';
$new_id = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $twitter_id);
```

`(?:http|https)` is a non-capture group matching either http or https, then you match the colon and the two slashes (escaping them, unless you use a different pattern delimiter).

You might also consider the case insensitive option for both above, e.g. `str_ireplace()` or `/pattern/i` (regex modifier)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind you could also use `str_replace` in this case:

```
$twitter_id = 'http://abcuser';
$needles = array('http://', 'https://');
$new_id = str_replace($needles, '@', $twitter_id);
// or use a simple regex
// $new_id = preg_replace('/(http|https)\:\/\//', '@', $twitter_id);
echo $new_id;
```